# What does a multiplexer do in CPU?

Tags: logic, hardware

I had designed a simple ALU, and I generated "operation codes" using a decoder. Now, I'm studying about Multiplexers, but I couldn't understand what they do in a CPU or ALU?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A really simple example: If you want to fetch a data bit from memory, a multiplexer allows you to specify an address (the input code), and the memory bit will be connected to another "pin".

So say you have 256 bits of memory, and you want to connect this to an output pin, the multiplexer has 8 bits for input codes.  You proved a code say N, and and bit N is connected through the logic gates to the output of the multiplexer. This multiplexer would have a total of 256 + 8 input lines.

I'm not sure how this would be implemented in more modern CPUs but you can probably see how several bit multiplexers could be stacked together and be used to fetch a byte from memory in parallel as well, and connected to say an arithmetic register to perform computations.

Fun right?!

Comment: this page seems to have some great information..http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_2.html  It also shows a "Demultiplexer"  http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_3.html which could be used to write to bits from a register... say the output register of an adder